# Add class to an image from tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, tinymce

I was wondering if it's possible to add a class to an image that is uploaded through tinyMCE.

I have this string that calls the description from my database.

```
<div class="articletext"><?$string = $image["description"];
```

Currently, to make the images responsive I add this inline css.

```
<style> img{width:100%; height:auto;}</style>
```

It works fine I just find it a bit sloppy and would like to see if there is a better way.

The output code looks like this when rendered: down by articletext is is where the image is shown.

```
<div class="grid_4">    
  <style> img{width:100%; height:auto;}</style>
    <div data-id="id-80">
      <article class="box white-bg mb-25">
        <div class="notices-title">Test Image In Post 1</div>
          <div class="newsdate" style="margin: 10px 0 !important;">February 26, 2014</div>
<div class="articletext"><p><img src="../../htp_filemanager/source/AllImages/bob-van-aubel-ray-bans.jpg" alt="bob-van-aubel-ray-bans" /></p>
<p>This is a test.</div>
```

What I'm looking for is a way to add `class="img-max"` automatically when an image is uploaded through tinyMCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the style below would solve the problem easily.

```
<style>.newsdate img{width:100%; height:auto;}</style>
```

Comment: it still messes with my other images on my page. I added the actual code I'm using in the update. code you show me where you would place that style.

Comment: <style>.articletext img{width:100%; height:auto;}</style>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `onChange` event of `TinyMCE` to keep track when the contents was modified along with
[addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add new class to your image:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   setup : function(ed) {
       ed.onChange.add(function(ed, l) {
           $('.newsdate img').addClass('img-max');
       });
   }
});
```

Comment: hey I tried your idea but could use some help, if your around would you mind chatting with my?